# Elasticsearch: SQL COUNT function does not work with subquery on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I migrated my old MySQL table to Elasticsearch. Now I'm trying to use the same SQL queries of my old database in the new one in order to get the same results; and I'm studying DSL to try to reproduce those queries using it.

The logs are related to the downloaded files in my system, then each new record/document contains the data of which file was downloaded. Something like this:

```json
{
  "_index": "download",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "90H",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "fields": {
    "id": [
      302
    ],
    "item_id": [
      "CM0513"
    ],
    "path": [
      "/path/file.png"
    ],
    "user_email": [
      "foo@bar.com"
    ],
    "@timestamp": [
      "2021-02-08T21:30:29.000Z"
    ],
    [...]
  }
}
```

The first query I have to do is to discover the number of downloaded files by each `item` to one user on a date (1 item contains N files that can be downloaded). Then, I used the following query (`query 1`):

```json
{
    "query": """
        SELECT item_id, COUNT(item_id) total_files, CAST(timestamp AS DATE) date, user_email
        FROM download
        GROUP BY item_id, CAST(timestamp AS DATE), user_email
        ORDER BY total_files DESC
    """
}
```

And I received the following output (I used a pandas dataframe to visualize the data):

```
  item_id  total_files                      date  user_email
0  CM0829        34043  2021-02-06T00:00:00.000Z  foo@bar.com
1  CM1130        32877  2021-02-06T00:00:00.000Z  foo@bar.com
2  CM0929        32072  2021-02-07T00:00:00.000Z  foo@bar.com
[...]
```

This was an expected output. The problem is with the second query that derives from the first one...

The second query is to discover the number of downloaded items. To do that, I need to count the number of rows from the output table above. Then, the query I used in my MySQL database was (`query 2`):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(subquery.item_id) total
FROM (
    SELECT item_id, COUNT(item_id) nofbs, CAST(timestamp AS DATE) date, user_email
    FROM select_download_user
    GROUP BY item_id, CAST(timestamp AS DATE), user_email
) subquery
```

The above query in my MySQL database returns a single number, for example `3500900`, but when I try to run it inside Elasticsearch, it does not return a number, it returns other data:

```
   total
0      1
1      4
2      7
3      2
[...]
```

```json
{
  "columns": [{"name": "total", "type": "long"}], 
  "rows": [[1], [4], [7], [2], [...]]
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to return the same datum from MySQL using Elasticsearch.

I thought about the possibility of executing the first query, get all records and count the result using pandas, however I did not find a way of returning all data in one request, the result is limited by pagination on Elasticsearch.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

I add below sample data and expected results to the queries:

- [Sample data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12hRa6NSrIwEfvAbTdWMz_Sc04_rAg2-t/view?usp=sharing)
- [Expected result to query 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ylvSq7THjCBSU25zSTWk2SHbAdYr3ALr/view?usp=sharing)
- Expected result to query 2 is: `18`

**EDIT 2:**

I'm trying to create a DSL script, but, at this moment, to no avail.

The last version of my DSL script is this:

```json
{
  "aggs": {
    "count_files": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "item_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count_files_by_users": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "user_email"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to make the second query using elasticsearch DSL? Can you please share some sample index data and expected search result ?

Comment: @ESCoder I edited my question to add the information you asked me. As I am new to ES, I have not yet been able to create a DSL script that does what I want, but I put the latest version of my attempt. Thank you for your help.

Comment: there is no `total_files` field in your sample index data. Do you want to sort the result in desc order on the basis of `total_files`?

Comment: My sample data are the records of my old MySQL table that I migrated to ES. `total_files` is calculated after executing `query 1` (expected result is the second CSV file). I sort query 1 with `total_files`, because I need to show these data on a table. Query 2 is a new count using the result of query 1.